# Create a custom filter with AND, OR statements

Tags: support, tags

I am new here and I was trying to create a custom filter with tags. Is it possible to create something like this:

Tagged with = 'python' and ('list' or 'dictionary' or 'numpy' or ...)

I mean, having the Python tag and having at least one of a series of other tags?

Because I noticed that if I use a broader tag like a language it overrides all possible inside libraries and specifications and if I use a tag like [integers] it leads to various different languages.

I didn't find anything about it and also I'm not sure if I should post this here or on Stack Exchange meta.

Comment: would a google search with tags and some more information not yield the answers you are looking for?

Comment: yes, for specific questions it does, but what if i wanted to create a specific filter so I can go threw all the most popular questions about a group of tags inside a language. I was writing in the create custom tag filter something like this: '[python] and [multithreading] or [python] and [multiprocessing] or [python] and [threadsafety]...' but there's got to be a better way right?

Comment: @tatarana i usually look for an answer to my question and i don't care that much where it comes from, but is still dn't understand what the use it is quite rare that i can't find a good answer

Comment: @Nick In your query, it is actually searching for a literal "and": `Results for **and** tagged with list or dictionary or numpy python Search options questions only`

Comment: @TheMaster Yes it does, I had intended to go back and update it but forgot. Update was to mention you can use something like `is:q ( [python] or [python3.x] ) ( [list] or [dictionary] or [numpy] )` to include not just python posts, but also python3.x posts, as parentheses are allowed but need to be separated from tags by spaces

Comment: @Nick  Great. Nice combo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure whether custom filter supports it, but you could  use a search query:

> [list]or [integer] or [dictionary][python] is:q

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blist%5Dor+%5Binteger%5D+or+%5Bdictionary%5D%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq

Comment: I couldn't make it work on custom filter but it works perfectly on the search box and I can save the url. thanks!