# Custom Filter - filter by score

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering, search-box, custom-filter

I want to create a custom filter for a tag. 
I can normally click on the tag, open the filter options and select what I want to filter, like

Filter by:

- No answers
- No accepted answer

... etc.

But now I want to filter out question with a negative score.

I know I can do that in the search-box with

```
[my-tag] score:0..
```

This even correctly yields `Search options score>= 0`.

My question is, how do I add this criteria to my *custom filter* so that I can save it? Is that possible?

If it isn't, I'd like to suggest that feature. Because I'd rather not work with the search-box + a ton of bookmarks.

Combining the powerful advanced search parameters with savable custom-filters would be extremely convenient!

---

<sub>Probably related: [Create a custom filter with AND, OR statements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401759/create-a-custom-filter-with-and-or-statements)</sub>